# QueryRow.Scan() doesn't read values properly?

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a row like this:
[image]

Now I want to retrieve the **checkin_time** and **checkout_time**:
[image]

OK I already got the correct query. Now run the query via Go code:

```
package controllers

import (
    "absensi/config"
    "absensi/models"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func DoScanRow(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var tmpcheckintime string
    var tmpcheckouttime string
    var param models.CheckinParam
    var db = config.DBConnect()
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&param)

    query1 := `SELECT checkin_time, checkout_time FROM oc_log WHERE userid=$1 AND userdate=$2;`
    row := db.QueryRow(query1, param.UserId, time.Now().Format("2006-01-02"))
    row.Scan(&tmpcheckintime, &tmpcheckouttime)

    fmt.Println("--> id: " + param.UserId)
    fmt.Println("--> date: " + time.Now().Format("2006-01-02"))
    fmt.Println("--> checkin: ", tmpcheckouttime)
    fmt.Println("--> checkout: ", tmpcheckouttime)

}
```

If I send this payload via Postman:

> { "id": "1234", "location": "(100,100)", "distance": 4 }

I get this:

> --> id: 1234
>
> --> date: 2019-10-28
>
> --> checkin:
>
> --> checkout:

Both checkin and checkout time are empty. Yet obviously only the checkout time is empty. What's wrong here?

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by Scan.

Comment: Hmm I got this error: "2019/10/29 17:50:32 http: panic serving [::1]:57463: sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "checkin_time": converting NULL to string is unsupported"

Answer (score 1):

The last two lines of code you post have you logging `tmpcheckouttime` twice in a row:

```
    fmt.Println("--> checkin: ", tmpcheckouttime)
    fmt.Println("--> checkout: ", tmpcheckouttime)
```

If you fix the first `Println`, do you get what you expect?

Comment: Aarrghh typo. After fixing the first `Println` (should use tmpcheckintime), well the result is still empty.